# sending http request from azure web app to my machine

Tags: node.js, express, http, azure-web-app-service

I created an azure web app which send an http request:

```
axios.post('http://*mypublicip*:3000/write/' + Name, {
  content: data[1]
})
```

meanwhile my computer has a running express server:

```
app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

all my functionality works when I use it locally by sending the request to localhost instead of my ip.
I also tried adding host '0.0.0.0' to my app.listen.
what am I missing? thanks

Comment: What configuration steps have you taken to ensure that port 3000 on your machine is exposed to the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This problem has nothing to do with your webapp**.

**So I will not test the webapp program anymore, you can access your http request of `http://*mypublicip*:3000/write/' + Name` through other machines (not PCs in the LAN) , My test environment is vm built in azure. You will find that your request cannot be accessed successfully.**

The reason is that the `ip` you found in `ipconfig` in `cmd` should not be your host `ip`, but the Internet ip assigned to you by the operator. This `ip` is used by many hosts. Simply put, this `ip` is not just one of yours Machines.

So cause your problem to happen. It is recommended to use intranet penetration tools to achieve this. It means to use the intranet penetration tool to expose your 3000 port.

**To solve your problem, I used `ngrok`.**

1. Build the project locally and monitor port `3000`.

[image]

2. Local visit, check the effect.

[image]

3. Access in the virtual machine, discovery failed.

[image]

4. After installing ngrok, the virtual machine accesses the new address and it succeeds.

**First allow port 3000 to be exposed.**

[image]

Test in vm, it works.

[image]