# how to connect express app in VM from internet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, azure-web-app-service

I am running an express app in node.js on Azure Linux VM, and I want to connect this website from my personal computer.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => 
{
    console.log("Server is running..");
})
```

And for ex. in my computer, I can just run localhost:3000 but on VM, I cant reach.

The public ip adress of VM is 40.XXX.XX.252 and I try to connect on my browser like this : http://40.XXX.XX.252:3000  but it doesn't work either..

I know it is really common question but i tried everything that is suggested and I couldnt fix.

ps: I tried to run this app on my computer and again, I could connect through localhost:3000 but not from another computer with my computer's public ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem causes:**

It must be that port 3000 is not open. You can open port 3000 through commands to set it. (The settings in the firewall also need to be checked)

**But I personally think this is not safe.**

I recommend using an intranet penetration tool, which is the safest way to access through the generated link, because sometimes the public ip assigned by the operator is not fixed. Here I recommend using [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/download) linux version.

You also can refer to my answer in another post.

[image]

[sending http request from azure web app to my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093518/sending-http-request-from-azure-web-app-to-my-machine/65102034#65102034)