# Is there a way to connect to desktop application/local database from cloud?

Tags: .net, azure, sockets, networking, desktop

I'm developing **mobile report app** that should **take all data from desktop application** that installed for each client. Desktop application has own MariaDB database and installed on PC that have access to the Internet. Also I have services on Microsoft Azure and can create new ones to deliver data between PC and mobile but I don't want to store all data in cloud for cost/sync reasons and want to connect directly to desktop HTTP API. What is the best way to do such stuff? I'm not sure how to resolve local PC IP that can be **dynamic**. Should I use sockets or some sort of hole punching?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `ngrok`  in your local pc.

[1. Connect your local web site.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093518/sending-http-request-from-azure-web-app-to-my-machine/65102034#65102034)

[2. Connect your local db.](https://ngrok.com/docs)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Architecting such feature has no sense.
You should store periodically your PC clients data into an Azure table Storage 100GB has a 4$ monthly cost then create an Azure API service to serve data to your mobile clients.